# Can't create conda env from environment.yml

Tags: python, conda

[The documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file) seems clear that I should do this:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate d2v
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate
```

But then `conda activate d2v` says "Could not find conda environment: d2v" and there is indeed no sign of d2v in the environments list. This has been a recurring issue across several systems and in fact I've *never* managed to create an env from environment.yml. How can I begin to debug this?

At least the manual approach `conda create --name d2v` still works.

Here's my conda info:

```
(base) me@mymachine:/data/me/repos/design2vec$ conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : /data/me/software/miniconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/me/.condarc
 populated config files :
          conda version : 4.6.7
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.7.1.final.0
       base environment : /data/me/software/miniconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /data/me/software/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /home/me/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /data/me/software/miniconda3/envs
                          /home/me/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.7 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.1 Linux/4.15.0-34-generic ubuntu/18.04.1 glibc/2.27
                UID:GID : 1003:1003
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: hello @zkurtz have u mentioned python version while creating environment. Which OS you are working on ?

Comment: python 3.7.1 (via miniconda) and OS = Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Answer (score -1):

Try this >

- sudo ln -s /home//miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh
- export PATH="/home//miniconda3/bin:$PATH"